# Efficient data structure of objects in python for lookup based on any object member variable

Tags: python, data-structures

I need to store objects that have a number (>2) of integer member variables and do quick look-ups using any member variables as a search key.

For easier illustration let's say the objects are tuples of 3 integers and I need to do quick look-ups using any element of a tuple as a key in a list of such tuples:

```
collection = [(1, 200, 9), 
              (2, 300, 8), 
              (3, 400, 7)]
```

Look-ups would be like:

```
collection.lookup_by_first_element(1) # Return (1, 200, 9)
collection.lookup_by_second_element(300) # Return (2, 300, 8)
collection.lookup_by_third_element(250) # Return None
```

I need the lookups to be fast/efficient. My best bet so far is to use an in memory sqlite database with three columns for the three tuple elements and put indexes on all three columns.

A search tree would also do, but those have one key for lookup and I don't see how could I do lookups based on more than one key. How would you do it?

Comment: This can be done with N dictionaries for unique values, N mutli-maps for non-unique. Put them in a class and give the accessors descriptive names.

Comment: values are always unique? If not, you want just the first tuple to have it?

Comment: To clarify: Values are unique across *all* columns, or just one? i.e., if `(1,2,3)` appears, can `(3,4,5)` appear?

Comment: @Thenatos: in my situation (3,4,5) can't appear, but now I'm also curious of a solution that let's (3,4,5) appear as well.

Comment: @kadam, a dictionary-based solution is likely to be more efficient than any numpy/array-based solution. See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> collection = [(1, 200, 9),
...               (2, 300, 8),
...               (3, 400, 7)]
>>> collection = np.array(collection)
>>> def f(d, c, v):
...     # d: collection, c: column, v: value
...     if np.any(d[:, c]==v): return d[d[:, c]==v]
...     return 'None'
...
>>> f(collection, 0, 1)
array([[  1, 200,   9]])
>>> f(collection, 1, 300)
array([[  2, 300,   8]])
>>> f(collection, 2, 250)
'None'
```

Comment: Sorry to be a critic, but this is way, way slower than using a dict. See my updated answer.

Comment: There are faster ways. See Senderle's answer below.

Answer (score 11):

This is a simple solution. You could easily put this in a class and provide a neater interface.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> collection = [(1, 200, 9),
...               (2, 300, 8),
...               (3, 400, 7)]
>>> keyed_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for tup in collection:
...     for i, e in enumerate(tup):
...         keyed_dict[(i, e)].append(tup)
... 
>>> keyed_dict[(1, 300)]
[(2, 300, 8)]
```

**Update**:

For what it's worth, the above is way faster than the [numpy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091549/efficient-data-structure-of-objects-in-python-for-lookup-based-on-any-object-memb/6092188#6092188) for lookup:

```
from timeit import timeit

setup_code = '''
import numpy

clen = {0}  # use .format() to fill this value
collection = [(n, (n + 1) * 100, clen - n) for n in xrange(clen)]

npcollection = numpy.array(collection)

def numpy_lookup(collection, column, value):
    if numpy.any(collection[:, column] == value): return collection[collection[:, column] == value]
    return 'None'

keyed_dict = dict()
for tup in collection:
    for i, e in enumerate(tup):
        keyed_dict[i, e] = tup
'''

for e in range(5):
    setup = setup_code.format(str(10 ** e))
    kd_stmt = '[keyed_dict[0, n] for n in range({0})]'.format(str(10 ** e))
    np_stmt = '[numpy_lookup(npcollection, 0, n) for n in range({0})]'.format(str(10 ** e))
    print 'using keyed_dict: ',
    print timeit(stmt=kd_stmt, setup=setup, number=10)
    print 'using numpy_lookup: ',
    print timeit(stmt=np_stmt.format(str(10 ** e)), setup=setup, number=10)
```

output:

```
using keyed_dict:  1.09672546387e-05
using numpy_lookup:  0.000250101089478
using keyed_dict:  3.00407409668e-05
using numpy_lookup:  0.00193691253662
using keyed_dict:  0.000190019607544
using numpy_lookup:  0.0199580192566
using keyed_dict:  0.00195384025574
using numpy_lookup:  0.317503929138
using keyed_dict:  0.0319399833679
using numpy_lookup:  15.0127439499
```

Comment: Ah, I see that values are unique. Well, just use a regular dict instead of a defaultdict.

Comment: I implemented your method in a class and tried to explain why O(1) dict lookups are faster than array based searching (that's O(N)) in my answer below (which you demonstrated quite well by benchmarking with `timeit`, but not saying why it should be so much faster).

Answer (score 6):

senderle is right (I upvoted), but I want to elaborate (and more than just in a comment).

Dictionary lookups are O(1) and really fast (basically your key gets turned into a hash that addresses a specific location in memory to immediately retrieve your data from).

In contrast looking for a value by searching through an array is slow at least O(N), so for larger arrays it will take longer to find the right value.  (E.g., you have to sift through all N keys, find the right one, and then can return the tuple.)

So if your keys are unique as you say, it makes sense to just create a large dictionary that is indexed based on every key you may use to lookup.  Granted is you will have to represent each tuple of m items (m=3 in your case), m times in the dictionary while with a single array it only had to be represented once in the array.

So you want to define a Collection class

```
class Collection(object):
    def __init__(self, collection):
        self.collection_dict = dict()
        for tup in collection:
            for i, v in enumerate(tup):
                self.collection_dict[(i, v)] = tup
    def lookup_by_first_element(self, e):
        return self.collection_dict.get((0, e), None)
    def lookup_by_second_element(self, e):
        return self.collection_dict.get((1, e), None)
    def lookup_by_third_element(self, e):
        return self.collection_dict.get((2, e), None)


collection = [(1, 200, 9), 
              (2, 300, 8), 
              (3, 400, 7)]
c = Collection(collection)
```

The internal `c.collection_dict` is:

```
{(0, 1): (1, 200, 9),
 (0, 2): (2, 300, 8),
 (0, 3): (3, 400, 7),
 (1, 200): (1, 200, 9),
 (1, 300): (2, 300, 8),
 (1, 400): (3, 400, 7),
 (2, 7): (3, 400, 7),
 (2, 8): (2, 300, 8),
 (2, 9): (1, 200, 9)}
```

And your lookups work as you requested

```
>>> c.lookup_by_first_element(1) == (1, 200, 9)
True
>>> c.lookup_by_second_element(300) == (2, 300, 8)
True
>>> c.lookup_by_third_element(250) is None
True
```

Comment: Was there a reason you used a `dict` instead of `defaultdict` as in senderle's answer? He used `list` as the `default_factory` for the `defaultdict`, so the resulting structure is different. Your dict has 2-tuple keys that point to 3-tuple values, where senderle's has 2-tuple keys that point to list values each containing a 3-tuple. I guess given tuples are immutable there's no default_constructor benefit gained when you want tuple values in the dict.

Comment: @Davos - OP claimed each key is [unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091549/efficient-data-structure-of-objects-in-python-for-lookup-based-on-any-object-mem/6099053#comment7059942_6091549) and wanted each lookup to return a tuple not a list of tuples.  I agree this seems to be a weird setup, but it could have use cases.  E.g., if each column is a unique identifier that will never be repeated (e.g., employee_id_number, email address, SSN).  Agree in a more general if it's something like (name, birth_date, home_town), then you would want a search to return a list of matching tuples.

Comment: Thanks I missed that comment about them being unique, that explains it. When they are unique, the other answer creates a structure where an entry looks like this `(0, 1): [(1, 200, 9)],` so the tuple is kind-of redundantly boxed in a list (of 1), which puzzled me.